# How to extract only feet from image using opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have an image of feet and I want to extract only feet from the image and remove all other background stuff.

I tried to do this by edge detection methods of OpenCV but those don't work for me as I want.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('D:/Desktop data/img2.jpg')
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 0)
# img_lap = cv.Laplacian(img_blur, cv.CV_64F)
img_canny = cv.Canny(img_blur, 150, 30)

cv.imshow('img_blur', img_blur)
# cv.imshow('img_lap', img_lap)
cv.imshow('img_canny', img_canny)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is an example image
[image] from which I want to extract feet only.

and here is an example image [image] with extracted feet only and I want the results like this image

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use cv2.inRange() to threshold on skin color of the feet. However, in your original image, you will also get the hands.

Comment: There could be a difference in the color of feet and maybe there could be background color like the skin of the feet. So I want a solution which should extract only feet in all cases.

Comment: I suspect you will need a deep learning / AI approach that uses lots of training data.

Answer (score 1):

if you want robust result, deeplearning based semantic segmentation is what you are looking for
https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/a-2019-guide-to-semantic-segmentation-ca8242f5a7fc

Comment: This looks good to me, But my requirement is to use OpenCV. I will go to deep learning if I could not get the robust results from OpenCV. Thanks

Comment: @rizwan OpenCV have good apis for deeplearning models to run nowadays.